# python regex - removing 'word' while keeping ['word']

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to remove `Opportunity` while keeping '[Opportunity]'.

```
Winery Tailspin Electonic Opportunity   [Opportunity].[Opportunity Name]
```

How do I do that?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

You can use count parameter in re.sub as below if it occurs always before your '[word]'.

```
    re.sub('Opportunity','',string,count = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what do you want with [Opportunity Name] bit, but following line will remove all Opportunity which have not adjacent [ or ]:

`re.sub('([^\[])(Opportunity)([^\]])','\g<1>\g<3>',string)`

This code use grouping in regex and match strings in form of
(any character different than [)(Opportunity)(any character different than ])
then replace with first and third group i.e. adjacent characters.
Using your example would give in effect

`Winery Tailspin Electonic    [Opportunity].[Opportunity Name]`

Notice however, that this solution will work if and only if Opportunity is not first and not last word. Is this true in your case?